# OnePage checkout additional address zone/region drop down not working

Tags: opencart, checkout, dropdown

I am having issue with Onepage checkout , whenever i go on checkcout page and try to add additional address zone/region drop down display empty options. if i select any other country and select my country again then zone/region options in drop down become active. Can any one help. i'm much frustrated with this problem.

Let me know if You need any info from me?

Thanks waiting for help

Comment: btw i'm using OC 1.5.6.4 with custom theme

Comment: @shadyyx can you look into it ? thanks